# return a value from $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, async-await

I need to build a function that does return me the visitor's country code, like this:

```
function getIsoCodeFromIp() {
    try {
        var response = await $.get("http://ip-api.com/json", null, "jsonp");
        return response.countryCode;
    } catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

how should I return this reponse?

I have a JSON, I need as output a two letter string, nothing more nor less, but it seems to be very complicated with this asynchronous approach to do such simple things.

I don't need to log it to the console, I need to **RETURN** it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this can be resumed in a function like this

```
fetch('http://ip-api.com/json')
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then((d) => console.log(d.countryCode));
```

surely, the question was about the how to return a string, and not just log the answer.

However if we find a way to chain the asynchronous call this will be the best answer and performance.. Now, if we want a synchronous return with the thread blocking... I never found an answer on that question... probably everybody will try to convince to remain with the first solution only...

By eg. you can chain calls to obtain desired result. Say, you need to obtain a ISO3 country code from the ISO2 coutry code of the first call. In order to use the second API for the ISO3 country code you could have to do the following:

```
fetch('http://ip-api.com/json')
        .then((j1)=>j1.json())                           // get iso2 country code
    .then((iso2)=>fetch('http://country.io/iso3.json')
        .then((j2)=>j2.json())                           // get iso3 code  
    .then((iso3)=>console.log(iso3[iso2.countryCode]))); // combine 1st result & 2nd
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `await` only in `async` function.

```js
// placed `async` before function
async function getIsoCodeFromIp() {
    try {
        var response = await $.get("http://ip-api.com/json", null, "jsonp");
        return response.countryCode;
    } catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
}

// async function returns Promise, use then(callback)
getIsoCodeFromIp().then(function(result){
    console.log(result); //here
});
```

Now it **returns Promise** because it is async function. You need to catch response by `then()` function.

Comment: is there a way to return however, not a promise, but a string?

Comment: Not with asynchronous functions and `&.get` is asynchronous so you have to `await` for that. That's why Promises exist.